# how redirect user after email verification in laravel 8 and nuxtjs

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js

how redirect user after email verification in laravel 8 and nuxtjs ??

**email verification code**

```
   public function verify(Request $request)
{
    auth()->loginUsingId($request->route('id'));

    if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {

        return response(['message'=>'Already verified']);

        // return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

      return response(['message'=>'verified']);

}
```

how redirect user to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Please pay attention to the code format and alignment also when posting an answer or a question.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your notification file (e. Notifications/VerifyEmailNotification.php) :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
        {
            $spa_url = env('SPA_URL') . '/email/verify/';
    
            $id =  $notifiable->getKey();
            $hash = sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification());
    
            $spa_url .= "{$id}/{$hash}";
    
            $url = UrlSigner::sign($spa_url, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)));
    
    
            return (new MailMessage)
                        ->line('Please click the button below to verify your email address.')
                        ->action('Verify Email Address', url($url))
                        ->line('This link expires in 1 hour and can only be used once. You can always request another link to be sent if this one has been used or is expired.');
        }
```